# How to verify apple authorization code in asp net core API?

Tags: c#, flutter, asp.net-core, authentication, apple-sign-in

I have problem. I have IOS App in Flutter. I added AppID and Service ID but I dont undersant what domain and redirect url I have to add in apple settings.

I have rest API in asp net core. I sign in Apple in Flutter aplication and get authorization code and jwt token.
What I have to do in API? I must verify something at Apple Servers? Can someone explain me how to do this step by step?

I tried send post from webside like reqbin to generate token to apple with authorization code. I still have: Invalid client. I dont undersant how correctly build client_secret and what I must put to redirect_uri. Signature key must be from AppId ??

Can someone explain me step by step what I should do? I tried to do this from a week...
Now I try to register user in my api by data from sign in token from flutter and dont connect API with apple servers. But I think this isn't good idea...

Comment: I'm guessing there is probably some good documentation over on Apple's developer site regarding authentication and authorisation.